# Web Video Player to play on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: internet-explorer, video, windows-phone-8, streaming, rtmp

Sorry to ask if this is the dummy question but i still do NOT know how to play my Videos, in the IE for WP8 Phones. I never have simple and successful solution.

### I have

I have a Video Streaming Website which can play on Desktops / Android / iOS devices, machines. But never on WP8 IE. I have following stream types:

- rtmp://......... ........./channel-1 *(Can be used for Flash)*
- rtsp://......... ........./channel-1 *(Can be used for Androids)*
- http://......... ........./channel-1/playlist.m3u8 *(Can be used for iOS, with html5)*

Then i am rendering suitable ones out to the browser (by detecting them) with:

- `<object.....` or
- `<a href="rtsp://...` or
- `<video...`

### Can i use

I never needed any of third-party player until i need to think about the weird WP8. Then now what? In order to play those streams on WP8 Devices, do i need to use ..

- Flow Player?
- JWPlayer?
- or what?

I never find any simple (like above) and successful solution for WP8. **But just YouTube** (how they do?) They can surprisingly play their videos on WP8 phones!
Please suggest at your best you have!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why YouTube Player can play on IE of Windows Phones?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397918/why-youtube-player-can-play-on-ie-of-windows-phones)

Comment: If you can read carefully, this one is NOT about Youtube!!

Comment: I read carefully, and i know this is not about youtube, but the question body of the two threads is exactly the same, maybe this is a bit more extended, but if you compare your two threads, you can see you post nearly the same in both. Thats the reason to say this is possible a duplicate.