# Why YouTube Player can play on IE of Windows Phones?

Tags: windows-phone-8, youtube, video-streaming, rtmp

I've been trying to make my Video Streaming (Website) to play on Windows Phones (WP8) but still never get any solution.

I have following kind of streams, which can play on Desktops / Androids / iOS:

- rtmp://......... ........./channel-1 *(Can be used for Flash)*
- rtsp://......... ........./channel-1 *(Can be used for Androids)*
- http://......... ........./channel-1/playlist.m3u8 *(Can be used for iOS, with html5)*

But never on Windows Phones. And i still DON'T KNOW how to.

### BUT

But YouTube can! Whenever i watch YouTube on WP8, i can watch the videos!

### HOW?

This is the one i need! Can anyone explain me how to do it please? *(Based on the stream types i have above)*

Answer (score 1):

Options are 3:

1. allow progressive download of MP4
2. get HLS support for MMPPF via something like http://www.linkedin.com/company/3013925/hls-sdk-for-microsoft-platforms-1530856/product
3. Create a smoothstream or MPEG-DASH stream

MMPPF found here http://smf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you for giving some hopes. I think I can get SmoothStreaming with my streaming server. How can I use it please? Especially for WP platform. Any clear examples?

Comment: Check out MMPPF found here http://smf.codeplex.com/  there are examples and "how to's" on the site http://smf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SMF%20v2%20%22How%20To%22%20Documentation&referringTitle=Home